# Write a predicate for reverse list

Tags: prolog

someone asks a question about Prolog, But I even don't know what does he mean can someone explain to me??

toggles back-and-forth from reverse

```
 ?- togglesturn([11,12,13,14,15],[13],L). L = [13, 12, 11, 14, 15]. 

?- togglesturn([11,a,13,15,hi,15,17,t],[15,a,a],L). L = [a, 11, 13, 15, 15, hi, 17, t].
```

can someone see the pattern and explain to me what does turn does???